# How to get formatted date twice, ensuring it's the same time?

Tags: bash, date

I have a Bash script which uses:

```
THE_DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S"`
```

To get the current date and time in a format which can be used to `mkdir` new directory.

But, for report generation, I use something like:

```
REPORT_DATE=`date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`
```

Which is the same, but different, if you see what I mean.

This means running `date` twice, and I understand that it's possible (although unlikely) for the seconds component to different between the two.

How, do I get the date in two different formats at the same time?

Comment: You can get the date once and then convert it between formats using `sed`/`awk` or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the date in a well-known format, and then pass it to `date` (using `-d`):

```
date="$(date +%s)"
the_date="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S' -d "@${date}")"
report_date="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d "@${date}")"
```

`%s` gets us the time in [Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which we can later use to make `date` print a *specific* time, instead of the current. The `@` prefix gives `date` a hint of the format.

It's possible that some other format could be used, but Unix time seemed the most universal and least error-prone.

<sup>(Off-topic: Don't use uppercase variable names, and use `$()` instead of backticks.)</sup>

Comment: But, for the off-topic stuff, I have to use uppercase variable names - I have to work to a coding standard. Please don't argue about that, I can't change it, and I don't have time to open that debate anyway.

Comment: @Nick I'm not saying you *can't* use uppercase; I'm saying you *shouldn't*. And if there's a coding standard you should follow it, but in this case also question it.

Comment: One more thing, why shouldn't I use backticks instead of $( ) ? I've used the backticks way for over 30 years - has it always been considered bad form?

Comment: @Nick Backticks still *work*, but are considered deprecated by most users these days. Read more [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082).

Answer (score 1):

You can call `date` only once, separating both dates by a newline (or other character) and read them:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r the_date report_date < <(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S%n%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"; printf '\0')
```

or, similarly but with two calls to `read`:

```
{ read -r the_date; read -r report_date; } < <(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S%n%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

So, basically, my answer is about calling `date` only once, and parsing its output…

---

As a side-note, since Bash 4.2, you can use the builtin `printf` instead of the external `date`:

```
{ read -r the_date; read -r report_date; } < <(printf "%(%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S%n%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S)T\n" -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPORT_DATE="$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")"
# Edit: Incorrect and slow: THE_DATE="$(echo "${REPORT_DATE}" | tr -d ":")
THE_DATE="$(echo "${REPORT_DATE//:}" | tr -d " " "-")"
```

Comment: In `bash`, `THE_DATE=${REPORT_DATE//:}` would be simpler and more efficient. You're missing the extra hyphen between day and hour in `THE_DATE`, however.